# Hibernate: Set property field to static final object instance

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I would like to create static final instances in my application that I can use to drive logic. An example of this would be:

```
public class ChargeStatusType {

private String code;
private String value;
private ChargeStatusType(String code, String value){
    this.code = code;
    this.value = value;
}

public static final ChargeStatusType APPROVED = new ChargeStatusType("APPROVED", "Approved");
public static final ChargeStatusType COMPELTED = new ChargeStatusType("COMPLETED", "Completed");
public static final ChargeStatusType CANCELLED = new ChargeStatusType("CANCELLED", "Cancelled");
public static final ChargeStatusType FAILED = new ChargeStatusType("FAILED", "Failed");
```

}

which is then used in

```
@Entity
@Table(name="charge_result")
public class ChargeResult extends RepresentationModel<ChargeResult> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;

    private ChargeStatusType chargeStatusType;
```

I am having issues saving ChargeResult as Spring / Hibernate does not know what to do with ChargeResult.ChargeStatusType.

Besides converting ChargeStatusType to an enum, is there a way to persist ChargeResult with a ChargeStatusType?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring `chargeStatusType` as a type of `ChargeStatusType` you can declare it as a `String` and persist that `String` then get the value using a static map like so

```
@Entity
@Table(name="charge_result")
public class ChargeResult extends RepresentationModel<ChargeResult> {
    private static final Map<String, String> chargeStatusType;
static{
    chargeStatusType = new HashMap<>();
    chargeStatusType.put("APPROVED", "Approved");
    chargeStatusType.put("COMPLETED", "Completed");
    chargeStatusType.put("CANCELLED", "Cancelled");
    chargeStatusType.put("FAILED", "Failed");
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
Long id;

@Column
private String chargeStatusKey;

public String getChargeStatusKey(){
    return chargeStatusType.get(chargeStatusKey);
}
```